# VBA assign append formula to a range

Tags: excel, vba, matrix

```
matrixRange = "E2:H25"
matrixFormula = "=Append(Append(SUBSTITUTE(Input!B2,"",""),MatrixToList(Input!B3:B6,Input!C2:H2,Input!C3:H6),,,,1,1))"
addSheet.Range(matrixRange).Value = matrixFormula
```

After the execution, the formula in the range actually become:

```
"=@Append(Append(SUBSTITUTE(Input!B2,"",""),MatrixToList(Input!B3:B6,Input!C2:H2,Input!C3:H6),,,,1,1))"
```

it is the @ in the string that prevents excel from explaining.
Any idea?

Comment: Change `.Value` to `.Formula2`.

Comment: changed to Formula2. Then the @ disappeared.  That is fine. But the matrix all got a error flag like below:
`#SPILL! #SPILL! #SPILL! #SPILL!

Comment: #SPILL! errors are well documented online - there's some other data in the way that's preventing the formula results from being spilled.

Comment: ok. it succeed  if I use Sheet.cells(1, 1).Fomula2 = matrixFormula